# encryption in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

sir
how can i implement a custom encryption blowfish algorithm (apart from inbuilt feature providved by sfdc) on a visualforce page by make the use of apex class and custom controller.

The functionality of this page should be like this:-
I enter the object details on visualforce page in plain text and it will store the data in cipher text on object detail page.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We are glad to see you here. This question seems too broad however Yes it is possible if the encrypting algorithm is fast enough to be completed in synchronous trasaction. Salesforce being on cloud imposes lots of limitations which we call as governor limits which are necessary. If you need help with a particular issue while writing code, you can post it here, someone will definitely help you. Also Salesforce provides some inbuilt encryptions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could take a reference implementation of Blowfish, written in Java and adapt it for Apex.

By far, the easiest solution would be if you were happy with AES128, AES192, or AES256. In that case, you can just use the built-in function:

Overview of the class: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

Apex manual on the subject: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

Comment: no sir,i have to imlpement my own encryption algo rather than provided built in algo in salesforce .is it possible to implement